# How can we modify a value in the caller from the callee?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cpython

How can we modify a value in the caller from the callee?

In the code below, why is `exec` not modifying the value of the variable `xxxx` in function `bar`?

```
def foo(xcode):
    print("CODE: ", xcode)
    of = inspect.currentframe().f_back
    of_locals = of.f_locals
    of_globals = inspect.stack()[1][0].f_globals
    exec(xcode, of_globals, of_locals)
    del of


def bar():
    x = 1
    y = 2
    z = 3
    foo("x = y + z")
    print("x == ", x)
    print("x == 6? ", x == 6)

bar()
```

Comment: Where is `bar` defined?

Comment: two functions are named `foo`?

Comment: Running this code results in a `NameError` since `bar` is not defined. If you meant `foo()` instead of `bar()` then it would result in a `TypeError` since `foo` takes no arguments. Also `2 + 3 == 5` so why do you expect the result to be `6`?

Comment: The second `foo()` should be `bar()` I think

Comment: I don't know if this is possible. What you get from f_locals is a dictionary that gets collected - probably similar to `locals()` - from various sources: true locals, closures, …. The actual locals are stored in an array for performance reasons, I don't think there's a way to get access to it.

Comment: @L3viathan it's possible

Comment: Okay, `ctypes`, didn't think of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

adding the following line after the `exec` statement seems to work:

```
ctypes.pythonapi.PyFrame_LocalsToFast(ctypes.py_object(of), ctypes.c_int(0))
```

So, we have:

```
import ctypes
def foo(xcode):
    print("CODE: ", xcode)
    of = inspect.currentframe().f_back
    of_locals = of.f_locals
    of_globals = inspect.stack()[1][0].f_globals
    exec(xcode, of_globals, of_locals)
    ctypes.pythonapi.PyFrame_LocalsToFast(ctypes.py_object(of), ctypes.c_int(0))
    del of
```